# floating action button exception Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I need your help.

I have a problem with floating action button (FAB) on android.

I would like to have a map (google map) as fragment (template of android studio) and add a FAB on the bottom right of the map (like maps app).

That's compile and launch on my phone but even before the map was display, exception.

I have the key of the google maps API (the map only work fine).

in gradle :`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

so i can add in my activity_map.xml :

here my xml activity : 
`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/map"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

`

I have already try with button out of the fragment, with relative layout...

App crash on setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps) so it when it read the xml file.

here my activity code :
`public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.show();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i click on FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}`
```

here the exception :

```
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.evenear.evenear/io.evenear.evenear.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `MapsActivity` to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` and make sure it is using a `Theme.AppCompat` theme. This will allow you to use the support library widgets

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Comment: Yes thank you, i tried to make AppCompatActivity but for the theme, i don't know where ? In style.xml ? because i dont have Theme.AppCompat the IDE hilighted me that in red

Comment: Yes, in your styles.xml https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#Theme

Comment: Did you get it sorted out?

Comment: Yes I did. I change the Theme but i didn't find it first time because i searched in "android:Theme" but it's just (theme.AppCompat....)

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with appcompact version 
Change the Gradle as follows, do the sync now, and make sure sync is successful and without error.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i click on FAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

This method should stay out of `onCreate () { ... }`